# What determines if a post is editable?

Tags: support, editing, suggested-edits

I'd really like to fix a typo in this question: [Do we see color with higher frequency first?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/30433/2963)

But for some reason only the 'link' and 'flag' options are visible to me (no 'edit' or 'retag'). I've looked around the SO faq a bit, but nothing jumped out at me as to why this is the case, can anyone explain?

Answer (score 2):

I'll restate here Jeff's answer in [the analogous question in the mother meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81681/why-is-the-edit-button-disabled) for the benefit of any future users searching this meta with the same question.

> There are a handful of conditions where we will stop accepting edits:
>
> 1. A large number of suggested edits by you were rejected in the last day (absolute value) - if banned you will be banned for a week.
> 2. We are out of empty slots in the queue (currently 20 120 200)
> 3. There is an edit to a particular post that was not approved yet.
> 4. You are not logged in and the post is less than 10 minutes old.
>
> In the past no "edit" link would be shown at all; since July 2012 the edit link is disabled and the mouse hover tooltip will explain why an edit cannot be suggested, like "Account is not allowed to suggest edits".